# Upgrading ExpressionEngine database with already upgraded code?

Tags: expressionengine

If you've upgraded and EE site locally, and committed all of the changes through i.e. GIT, how are you supposed to upgrade the database on the production environment when you pull the upgraded codebase up to production? I've tried running the installer for the version the codebase is on but none of the migrations run. It says I'm already upgraded when the database is clearly still the older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version number is stored in **system/expressionengine/config/config.php**.

```
$config['app_version'] = "273";
```

In order for the migrations to run you have to change that version to the old version you upgraded from.